# What does Julia's backslash (\) operator do on two matrices?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

In the context of matrices, if we have `A\B` what mathematical operation is being executed on `A` and `B`. The documentation seems to state that it is division but I thought division was an invalid operation for matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can figure out which method is called by using `@which` (or `@edit`)

```
A = randn(10,2)
b = randn(10)
@which A\b
```

which leads to the implementation

```
function (\)(A::AbstractMatrix, B::AbstractVecOrMat)
    require_one_based_indexing(A, B)
    m, n = size(A)
    if m == n
        if istril(A)
            if istriu(A)
                return Diagonal(A) \ B
            else
                return LowerTriangular(A) \ B
            end
        end
        if istriu(A)
            return UpperTriangular(A) \ B
        end
        return lu(A) \ B
    end
    return qr(A,Val(true)) \ B
end
```

where you can see that what method is used depends on the structure of the matrices. In the absence of any useful structure, a QR factorization is performed, using which the linear system is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Julia documentation for linear algebra has the explanation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.:%5C%5C-Tuple%7BAbstractArray%7BT,2%7D%20where%20T,Union%7BAbstractArray%7BT,1%7D,%20AbstractArray%7BT,2%7D%7D%20where%20T%7D). "For input matrices A and B, the result X is such that A*X == B".

In the context of a square matrix `A`, `A\B` returns `inverse(A) * B`.

Comment: Note, despite computing `inverse(A)*B` it does so in a method that does not involve computing the inverse for reasons of precision and speed

Comment: But it works even if `A` is not square, what does `inverse(A)` mean then?

Comment: more specifically it returns `X` minimizing `||AX-B||`